# Grails app not working in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-tomcat-plugin

I have VPS and WHM installed on it,
I deployed war from tomcat manager and copied everything from
    /var/lib/easy-tomcat7/webapps/myDomain 
to 
    /home/myDomain/public_html/
Later I changed cp_jkmount.conf and added following contents

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
  JkMount /* ajp13
</IfModule>
```

Restarted apache and tomcat both,
Still home page is being shown as plain text.
you can see this here: [www.rockinexams.com](http://www.rockinexams.com)
Aparat from this,
I have build the war using tomcat 7.0.42 as plugin,
and the tomcat version present on VPS is same.
There are no errors or stacktrace in logs.
Is there something that I am missing and should try?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your problem is that all your css and js are pointing to "404-not found"

Comment: so i guess ressources-plugin has sth to do, consider update to `resources:1.2.RC2`

Comment: if its resource plugin problem, all pages should be displayed as plain text, but after home page I am not able travel to any other pages. Is that something related to controllers are not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue, www.rockinexams.com:8080 works but www.rockinexams.com doesn't, so I will have added following lines to my .htaccess file to make it work

```
SetHandler jakarta-servlet
SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

its working perfect now. !!!
Thanks all for suggestions.